# .NET framework, Windows XP

Tags: vb.net

We have built an app with Visual Studio 2012 and it runs beautifully on any Windows 7 or Vista machine, 32 or 64 bit. However, when I try to run the app on an Win XP machine, I get this:

**

> Prerequisite check for system component Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5
> (x86 and x64) failed with the following error message:
>
> "Installation of the Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 is not supported on
> this operating system. Contact your application vendor."

**

And then of course, when I try to install .NET 4.5 on the Win XP machine, I find out it's not supported.

At this point, I'm just wanting to know what can be done to get this app to run on Win XP. It's a calculator application written in visual basic.

Thanks Guys!

Comment: Just change the target framework to 4.0 (in project's properties). You may need to change your code (if you used 4.5 specific features).

Comment: fyi.. its by design 4.5 doesn't support xp http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/730732/net-framework-4-5-should-support-windows-xp-sp3

Comment: Related: [.NET Framework 4.0 does not install when 4.5 is already installed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14570827/55075).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.Net framework 4.5 is not supported in Windows XP. If you're not using any .Net 4.5 features you can rebuild your app using .Net Framework 4 (In the Project properties).

[image]

Comment: One last thing, I've been trying to figure out how to disable error reporting for the end user. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @MarkJeffords You should ask that in a new question (it'll be easier to find it'll get more attention).

Answer (score 1):

I always hate these kind of answers, but a quick google search indicates that you can't get .net 4.5 to run on Windows XP.

IF you really really need your application to run, you can always use earlier versions of the framework

you can do this by

Right click on your project and go to

- properties
- application
- target framework

and change that to something elxe