# Prerequisite check for system component Microsoft .NET Framework

Tags: .net-4.0, windows-services, clickonce, prerequisites, .net-framework-version

I have written a windows service in c# using ide visual studio 2012.
When I tried to install it on a windows server 2003 I got this error message:

> Prerequisite check for system component Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 (x86 and x64) failed with the following error message:
>   "Installation of the Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 is not supported on this operating system. Contact your application vendor."

So I went back into my project and set the target framework to 4.0.  I then rebuilt the solution, re-added the installer and published again.  However, when I try to install I get the exact same error.

For some reason it is not detecting that I have changed the framework to 4.0.  Any ideas where I have force this change or where even to look??

**Extra Info:**  It seems to be using click-once deployment.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14570975/43846

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I came up with was to create a new project with the correct .NET version.  Copied all my code across and it worked...  *shrug*

Answer (score 0):

*.NET Framework 4.5* is not supported on Windows XP, Windows Server 2003 and similar.

Supported Operating Systems (as per [*System Requirements* page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653&e6b34bbe-475b-1abd-2c51-b5034bcdd6d2=True)):

- Windows 7 Service Pack 1, Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows Server 2008 Service Pack 2, Windows Vista Service Pack 2
- Windows Vista SP2 (x86 and x64)
- Windows 7 SP1 (x86 and x64)
- Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 (x64)
- Windows Server 2008 SP2 (x86 and x64)

If you're using Wine to install it, run `winecfg` and change your Windows version to higher.

Otherwise install lower version of *.NET Framework* such as 3.0. If you're compiling the project, change it in [*Target framework*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14570975/55075).