# TDS project not loading while migrating solution from VS 2013 to VS 2017

Tags: sitecore, tds

I am in the process of migrating my solution from VS 2013 to VS 2017. I installed correct version of TDS (TDS 5.6.0.15 for VS 2017) and when trying to open the solution in VS 2017, TDS projects are not loading and throwing following error.

[image]

Tried an option in the error dialog box to convert TDS project to .net framework 4.6.1 but it does nothing and TDS projects are still not loading. Not sure how to fix it.

Do I really need .Net framework 4.0 installed on this machine?

Would appreciate if someone can chime in with solution for similar migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve this by re-installing VS 2010. I had VS 2010 which I uninstalled as I am not using it anymore but after reinstalling it back, I am able to load TDS project correctly in VS 2017.

Someone mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570827/net-framework-4-0-does-not-install-when-4-5-is-already-installed) a repair option, which I didn't try but looks like it can resolve such issues. May be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would try and adjust your project target Framework to be the 4.6.1 FW manually.  Then open TDS with the latest and greatest versions.  Good luck, I just upgraded...You will like it.